# How to completely uninstall Jenkins from OS X

Tags: uninstall, cleaning, jenkins

I tried to install Jenkins on my OS X, that was successfully but usage is not quite successful. So planning on complete/clean uninstall and redo it back.

Any help on what all the traces of Jenkins need to be cleaned up to avoid issues fresh installation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608996/how-to-uninstall-jenkins

Answer (score 11):

> These instructions apply if you installed using the official Jenkins
>   Mac installer from http://jenkins-ci.org/
>
> Execute uninstall script from terminal (admin password required):
>
> ```
> '/Library/Application Support/Jenkins/Uninstall.command'
> ```
>
> or use Finder to navigate into that folder and double-click on
>   Uninstall.command.
>
> Finally delete last configuration bits which might have been
>   forgotten:
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf /var/root/.jenkins ~/.jenkins
> ```
>
> If the uninstallation script cannot be found (older Jenkins version),
>   use following commands:
>
> ```
> sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
> sudo rm /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
> sudo rm -rf /Applications/Jenkins "/Library/Application Support/Jenkins" /Library/Documentation/Jenkins
> ```
>
> and if you want to get rid of all the jobs and builds:
>
> ```
> sudo rm -rf /Users/Shared/Jenkins
> ```
>
> and to delete the jenkins user and group (if you chose to use them):
>
> ```
> sudo dscl . -delete /Users/jenkins
> sudo dscl . -delete /Groups/jenkins
> ```
>
> These commands are also invoked by the uninstall script in newer
>   Jenkins versions, and should be executed too:
>
> ```
> sudo rm -f /etc/newsyslog.d/jenkins.conf
> pkgutil --pkgs | grep 'org\.jenkins-ci\.' | xargs -n 1 sudo pkgutil --forget
> ```

Source [How to uninstall Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608996/how-to-uninstall-jenkins), answer by [sti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1287080/sti)

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.